# AWS SDK .NET Fargate ECS Get ARN of current task

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We're using AWS fargate, and run services with a bunch of task.
For logging purposes i would like to know the ARN of the "current Task" (the task that the code is running on). Before we were using EC2 and i could the AWS SDK for .NET (Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.InstanceId) to get it.

So far i haven't found anything that could give met the ID / ARN of the task in the SDK or otherwise. Anyone aware of a way to retrieve this information?

To perhaps make it more clear which task ID / ARN i mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In boto3 the python3 SDK, it have `list_tasks(**kwargs)` as documented here: 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.list_tasks

Request Syntax

```
response = client.list_tasks(
    cluster='string',
    containerInstance='string',
    family='string',
    nextToken='string',
    maxResults=123,
    startedBy='string',
    serviceName='string',
    desiredStatus='RUNNING'|'PENDING'|'STOPPED',
    launchType='EC2'|'FARGATE'
)
```

Not a .NET person but this might be what you are looking for

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/ECS/MECSListTasksListTasksRequest.html

Comment: Thank you, but how would I know from that list on which of the returned items my current piece of code is running?

Comment: That information should come from the log stream, if you have cloudwatch logs setup. Use awslogs driver to stream logs from the container to cloudwatch

Comment: Yes, that's true. But i want to post the data of the machine to newRelic as a custom attribute. So if there errors that happen we can see if 't a specifc task that has issues or not.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-data-sources/custom-data/add-custom-attributes-new-relic-apm-data